# ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters. "Problem in curve fitting"

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python, so my knowledge is inadequate.
I have a datafile named "tlove_cc_seq2_k2_NL3.dat". I want to fit a curve to the data.
The code I am using is as follows::

...

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    import math
    import pandas as pd
    import lmfit
    from lmfit import Model
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    from array import *

    def test(x, a, b, c): 
         return (a + b*math.log(x) + c*math.log(x)**2)

    func = np.vectorize(test)

    data_k2_2fl_NL3=np.loadtxt('tlove_cc_seq2_k2_NL3.dat')
    plt.plot(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,5], 'b-', label='data')
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,5])
    popt

    plt.plot(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], func(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], *popt), 'r-',
             label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,5], bounds=(-20, 
    [30., 30., 20.5]))
    popt

    plt.plot(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], func(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], *popt), 'g--',
             label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

...

The error I am getting is as follows::

...
        ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
         in 
             13 #y = data[:, 1]
             14 plt.plot(data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,5], 'b-', label='data')
        ---> 15 popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,8], data_k2_2fl_NL3[:,5])
             16 popt
             17

```
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, 
    ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
        678         args, varargs, varkw, defaults = _getargspec(f)
        679         if len(args) < 2:
    --> 680             raise ValueError("Unable to determine number of fit parameters.")
        681         n = len(args) - 1
        682     else:

    ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.
```

How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `curve_fit` function cannot determine the number of parameters by introspection because the function you are asking it to fit (`test`) is wrapped in the `np.vectorize` function.

I tried a minimal example where I used the `test` function un-vectorized and it worked:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def test(x, a, b, c): 
        return (a + b*np.log(x) + c*np.log(x)**2)

func = np.vectorize(test)

#Create some dummy data
x_data = list(range(1, 11))
y_data = np.log(x_data) + np.log(x_data)**2 + np.random.random(10)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'b-', label='data')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(test, x_data, y_data)
popt
```

If you need `vectorize` for performance reasons you can also pass a parameter `p0` an array of initial parameters. e.g:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_data, y_data, p0=[1,1,1])
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to fit a dataset from a datafile. When I was not vectorizing I was getting an error like "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".                                                                                                                                                              As this is generated when an array of numbers is given as input in place of a single number, so I did vectorization. The main issue is I need to fit data from a file.

Comment: Can you try using `np.log` (like in my answer) in place of `math.log` in your `test` function? The numpy method accepts arrays.
Did passing an intialization vector `p0` not work?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Main issue was np.log. It takes array while math.log does not.

Comment: Great. If the answer solves your problem you can mark it as 'accepted' and then others know it is solved.

Comment: I've now upvoted the answer from M Newville as it shows a better use of lmfit. I hadn't used that package before and so rather narrowly got the errors to go away. It sounds like his answer shows a better way to use the package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most of the issues you had were with using `numpy` vs `math`. For completeness, and since you mentioned `lmfit`, to do this with `lmfit`, you could use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

def test(x, a, b, c): 
    return (a + b*np.log(x) + c*np.log(x)**2)

# create model from your model function
mymodel = Model(test)

# create initial set of named parameters from argument of your function
params = mymodel.make_params(a=0.5, b=1.1, c=0.5)

# Create some dummy data
x_data = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y_data = np.log(x_data) + np.log(x_data)**2 + np.random.random(len(x_data))

# run fit, get result
result = mymodel.fit(y_data, params, x=x_data)

# print out full fit report: fit statistics, best-fit values, uncertainties
print(result.fit_report())

# make a stacked plot of residual and data + fit
result.plot()
plt.show()
```

Note that `curve_fit()` will happily accept uninitialized parameters, assigning the impossible-to-justify default value of 1 for all parameters.  Lmfit does not allow this and forces you to explicitly set initial values.  But it also better reports fit statistics, uncertainties, and allows for composition of more complpex models.

For your example, the fit report will read

```
[[Model]]
    Model(test)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 8
    # data points      = 10
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.91573485
    reduced chi-square = 0.13081926
    Akaike info crit   = -17.9061352
    Bayesian info crit = -16.9983799
[[Variables]]
    a:  0.69752193 +/- 0.34404583 (49.32%) (init = 0.5)
    b:  1.17700278 +/- 0.59765274 (50.78%) (init = 1.1)
    c:  0.85298657 +/- 0.23838141 (27.95%) (init = 0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(b, c) = -0.961
    C(a, b) = -0.782
    C(a, c) =  0.607
```

and a plot of

[image]

Comment: Thanks for more detailed explanation and sharing your experience of lmfit. I hadn't used that package before.