# array([....])is not a callable object. What does this mean in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, callable

I am writing a python code to create a curve fit o a circle and plot it along with the original data. I followed examples here:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html
but cannot understand why this error is coming up in my code, saying the array is not callable. What does it mean? The last block of code after the comment "curvefit" is where the error occurs.
The error is as follows: (the array here is the result of calcCircleFunction() )

```
runfile('/untitled25.py', wdir='C:/XYZsara/testing/testing stj file')
r= 5
[10.          9.53518102  7.69656593  8.85865225 11.77599647 14.26300842
 16.59986154 18.86270235 21.08280172 23.27574271 25.45026401 27.6116804
 29.76342361 31.90781435 34.04648108 36.18060165 38.31104984 40.43848797
 42.56342747 44.68626971]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\untitled25.py", line 46, in <module>
    popt = curve_fit(circle, xTraj,yTraj)   #array of curve fit version of circles

  File "\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 686, in curve_fit
    args, varargs, varkw, defaults = _getargspec(f)

  File "\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py", line 298, in getargspec_no_self
    sig = inspect.signature(func)

  File "\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 3083, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)

  File "\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 2833, in from_callable
    follow_wrapper_chains=follow_wrapped)

  File "\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 2208, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))

TypeError: array([10.        ,  9.53518102,  7.69656593,  8.85865225, 11.77599647,
       14.26300842, 16.59986154, 18.86270235, 21.08280172, 23.27574271,
       25.45026401, 27.6116804 , 29.76342361, 31.90781435, 34.04648108,
       36.18060165, 38.31104984, 40.43848797, 42.56342747, 44.68626971]) is not a callable object
```

```
from random import random
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xi = 0
xf = 40
yi = 0
radius = 5
numPoints = 20
xdata = np.linspace(xi,xf,numPoints)

def calcCircleFunction(x):  #calculate the function of circle in 2D
    [a,b] = calcCenters(vars)
    print("r=",radius)
    circle = np.sqrt(abs((x-a)**2-radius**2)) + b
    return circle

def calcCenters(vars):
    a, b = fsolve(solve_ab, [1,1])
    return [a,b]

def solve_ab(vars):
    a,b = vars
    f1 = (xi-a)**2 + (yi-b)**2 - radius**2
    f2 = (xi-a)**2 + ((yi+2*radius)-b)**2 - radius**2
    f = [f1,f2]
    return f


circle = calcCircleFunction(xdata)
print(circle)

"""curvefit"""
xTraj = np.linspace(xi,xf,numPoints)
yTraj = circle + 0.01*random()   #with noise
#print(yTraj)
popt = curve_fit(circle, xTraj,yTraj)   #array of curve fit version of circles
plt.plot(xTraj, yTraj, 'b-')   #plots the originral trajecory
plt.plot(xdata, calcCircleFunction(xdata, *popt), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The first argument to `curve_fit()` is supposed to be a function. `circle` is an array.

Comment: `callable` is a general Python term for `function`, and similar constructs that can be `called`, e.g. `func(...)`.  `calcCircleFunction(xdata)` called the function with the `xdata` argument, returning an array.  No further `calling` is possible.  Don't skip too much of Python basics.  And keep the function reference (e.g. `scipy`) handy.

Comment: Thank you. I changed curve_fit(circle...) to curve_fit(calcCircleFunction... and it passes the error now. I am getting another error, "unable to determine number of fit parameters.Why does this happen? There was another question like this in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796489/valueerror-unable-to-determine-number-of-fit-parameters-problem-in-curve-fitt but I cannot see how it applies to my case. Could someone give me another help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `curve_fit`'s first argument requires a function, not array or list.